# Guice ThrowingProvider problem

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, provider

According to the [ThrowingProvider](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ThrowingProviders) documentation of Guice I have the following interface:

```
public interface IConfigurableProvider<T> extends ThrowingProvider<T, ConfigException> {}
```

I have multiple classes that implements this interface, let assume I have the following:

```
public class SomethingProvider extends ConfiguredProvider implements IConfigurableProvider<Something> {}
```

Of course this class implements the necessary method:

```
public Something get() throws ConfigException { /* ... */ }
```

In my module, I have the following code in `MyModule.java`

```
ThrowingProviderBinder.create(binder())
    .bind(IConfigurableProvider.class, Something.class)
    .to(SomethingProvider.class);
```

But when I start my application the following error produced:

```
6) No implementation for com.package.Something was bound.
  while locating com.package.Something
    for parameter 5 at com.package.OtherClass.<init>(OtherClass.java:78)
  at com.package.MyModule.configure(MyModule.java:106)
```

I don't really know where should I start looking for the bug.

*Update*: It provides the same error even if I set the scope as well:

```
ThrowingProviderBinder.create(binder())
    .bind(IConfigurableProvider.class, Something.class)
    .to(SomethingProvider.class)
    .in(Singleton.class);
```

Comment: As the accepted answer pointed out I misunderstood the usage of `ThrowingProviderBinder`. The injected constructor should wait for a provider instead of the provided object (and there should be the checked exception handled).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than injecting the `Something`, you need to inject the `IConfigurableProvider<Something>`:

```
public class OtherClass {
  @Inject
  public OtherClass(IConfigurableProvider<Something> somethingProvider) {
    ...
  }
}
```

This is because it is only in `OtherClass`'s code (or any code that uses an instance of `Something`) you can deal with exceptions thrown by the Provider, such as `ConfigException` in your case.

Comment: but I don't want to modify the constructors. is there any way to achieve what I really want?

Comment: I think I'll forget the `ThrowingProvider` and simply use the `Provider` interface and wrap the source exception into `ProvisionException`